# Angular filter in a nested element

Tags: angularjs, filter

How can i use AngularJS filter in a json like this:

```
For example i need to filter by custom_fields.cidade
```

something like:
$scope.posts = $filter('filter')($scope.postdata, {custom_fields.cidade:args});

I have a plunker with this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Xrfy4KZ02j5Ydy0bziqs

```
{
    "id": 289,
    "type": "cursos",
    "slug": "terapias-da-alma",
    "url": "http://cursosholisticos.com.br/cursos/terapias-da-alma/",
    "status": "publish",
    "title": "Terapias da Alma",
    "title_plain": "Terapias da Alma",
    "content": "<p>O Terapias da Alma voltará ao Rio de Janeiro para o Nível I! Venha beneficiar-se desta energia curadora, levando-o a um reencontro com um estado natural de harmonia, saúde e felicidade. Seja um canal de Reiki!</p>\n<p>Curso presencial de Reiki Nível I será ministrado pelo Mestre Nilton Magalhães Jr. Para matricular-se, entre em contato com (21) 98881-3719 (falar com Renata) ou para (27) 3084-9610 ou 99719-4990 (Vivo) / 99254-8836 (Claro) / 98810-1625 (Oi) (falar com Nilton), ou via W<span class=\"text_exposed_show\">hatsApp. Maiores informações acerca do curso, do local e do custo, acesse a Fan Page de &#8220;Terapias da Alma &#8211; Terapia Floral, Terapia Reiki e Cursos de Reiki&#8221;, pelo meu perfil no facebook ou ligue. O curso de Reiki Nível I é a base para todos os outros níveis!</span></p>\n<div class=\"text_exposed_show\">\n<p>Além da parte teórica, após a sintonização iniciará a prática, treinando os participantes a como se autoaplicarem Reiki.<br />\nNamastê!</p>\n</div>\n",
    "excerpt": "<p>O Terapias da Alma voltará ao Rio de Janeiro para o Nível I! Venha beneficiar-se desta energia curadora, levando-o a um reencontro com um estado natural de harmonia, saúde e felicidade. Seja um canal de Reiki! Curso presencial de Reiki Nível I será ministrado pelo Mestre Nilton Magalhães Jr. Para matricular-se, entre em contato com [&hellip;]</p>\n",
    "date": "2014-12-03 16:18:14",
    "modified": "2014-12-03 16:18:14",
    "categories": [],
    "tags": [
        {
            "id": 23,
            "slug": "terapias",
            "title": "Terapias",
            "description": "",
            "post_count": 7
        }
    ],
    "author": {
        "id": 1,
        "slug": "adm",
        "name": "adm",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "nickname": "adm",
        "url": "",
        "description": ""
    },
    "comments": [],
    "attachments": [],
    "comment_count": 0,
    "comment_status": "closed",
    "custom_fields": {
        "data": [
            "2014-12-14"
        ],
        "cidade": [
            "Rio de Janeiro"
        ],
        "local": [
            "Clínica Holística Nise da Silveira"
        ],
        "url": [
            "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=836973149656542&set=gm.340168176162848&type=1"
        ],
        "endereco": [
            "Rua Conde de Bonfim, 44 - sala 901 Tijuca "
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not related to the question but is a friendly reminder for the good of the community. Pedro, you have posted 24 questions but have not marked a single one as answered. Accepting answers that solve your problem is good both for helping future visitors and giving the answerer the reputation he/she deserves.

Comment: Tks for the feedback, my bad

Comment: No harm done, can still go back and accept the answers that helped you :)

Comment: Your example works fine, you just have one item in it, here's more items: http://plnkr.co/edit/TbeAltGwV7rm55pefCbK?p=preview